For which values of $\alpha$ the integral $\int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}\sin\frac1x}{x^{\alpha}+2x}dx$ is convergent?

Find all possible values of $\alpha$, so that the following integral be convergent:$$\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-x}\sin\frac1x}{x^{\alpha}+2x}dx$$
$1)\alpha> 1\qquad\qquad 2)\alpha<1\qquad\qquad 3)\alpha<2\qquad\qquad4)\alpha>0$

Here is my thought:
The indefinite integral doesn't look to have closed-form, so I think we should use some tests. I believe comparison test would be helpful here but not sure how to proceed. For $x\in[0,1]$, $x^{\alpha}$ increases when $\alpha$ decreases. So intuitively, I think it is better to make the denominator larger so that the fraction be smaller hence the answer is either $\alpha<1$ or $\alpha<2$. For $\alpha=1$ the integral is,
$$\dfrac13\int_0^1\dfrac{e^{-x}\sin\frac1x}{x}dx$$
Maybe using $u=\dfrac1x,\ldots$ would help?

Are you able to study the convergence of $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^a+2x}dx$?

Is $\alpha$ required to be positive?

@SineoftheTime No the problem didn't mention that.

Unless I'm making some stupid error, I think there's something wrong with the answers

@SineoftheTime. I fully agree with you. One option is missing, I think

@ClaudeLeibovici which range of $\alpha$ do you get? It looks like the integral converges for all $\alpha\in \Bbb R$

@SineoftheTime. Here also, I agree ! Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici Ok so it seems the problem is wrong. According to the answer sheet, the second option is right.

Change variables $u=1/x$ then integrate by parts to get
$$I(\alpha):=\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-1/u}\sin{u}}{u^{2-\alpha}+2u}du$$
$$= \frac{e^{-1} \cos{(1)}}{3}-\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}
\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{u}} \cos{u}}{u^{2-\alpha}+2 u}+$$
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{u} \;e^{-1/u}}{u^{4-\alpha}+2u^{3}} du+\int_{1}^{\infty}
e^{-1/u}\cos{u} \frac{(2-\alpha)u^{1-\alpha}+2}{(2u+u^{2-\alpha})^2}du$$
Now the limit is zero.
The first integral converges for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ because the numerator is uniformly bounded as follows
$$| e^{-1/u} \cos{u}|\leq 1$$
and $$u^{3}+u^{2-\alpha}> u^{3},\qquad \forall u\geq 1$$
The integrand in the last integral decays at least as fast as $\max(u^{-1-\alpha},u^{-3+\alpha})$ which equals $u^{-1-\alpha}$ if $\alpha\leq 1$ and
$u^{-3+\alpha}$ if $\alpha>1$. This is integrable for all $0<\alpha<2$. One can show that this is sharp by integrating by parts one more time.

There is an issue with the question for sure.

@user1380196 Tell me if there is something unclear to you.
